# Create new array from objects

Tags: javascript, jquery

I am making something to add employees, calculate their ages and then calculate their average age. I am returning json objects, but want to wrap them in a new array/json object. I am overlooking something simple :( can anybody help?

```
$('.calculateAverageAge').on('click', function() {
  $('.item').each(function(key, item){
    var val = {};
    // Huidige datum
    var currentDate = new Date();
    // Nette datum in json object en haal jaar uit geboortedatum
    var getCleanBirthday = $(item).find('.ageItem').val();
    var getBirthday = new Date(getCleanBirthday);
    // Jaren uit waardes halen
    var nowYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var pastYear = getBirthday.getFullYear();
    // Bereken leeftijd
    var getAge = nowYear - pastYear;
    // Naam ophalen
    var getName = $(item).find('.nameItem').val();
    // Maak json object
    var employee = {Employee:[{name: getName, birthdate: getCleanBirthday, age: getAge}]}
    console.log(JSON.stringify(employee));
  })
});
```

Comment: Could you put your full code into a [fiddle?](http://jsfiddle.net)

Comment: Could you show an example of a result you want?

Comment: What is the code doing currently? What is not working? Please read [MCVE].

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Use an `employees` array, push each new `employee` object into it, and then after the `each` has finished, stringify `employees`. Voila, an array of employee objects:

```
$('.calculateAverageAge').on('click', function() {
  var employees = [];
  $('.item').each(function(key, item){
    var val = {};
    // Huidige datum
    var currentDate = new Date();
    // Nette datum in json object en haal jaar uit geboortedatum
    var getCleanBirthday = $(item).find('.ageItem').val();
    var getBirthday = new Date(getCleanBirthday);
    // Jaren uit waardes halen
    var nowYear = currentDate.getFullYear();
    var pastYear = getBirthday.getFullYear();
    // Bereken leeftijd
    var getAge = nowYear - pastYear;
    // Naam ophalen
    var getName = $(item).find('.nameItem').val();
    // Maak json object
    employees.push({name: getName, birthdate: getCleanBirthday, age: getAge});
  });
  console.log(JSON.stringify(employees));
});
```

Comment: Thanks a bunch Andy, that was it. I knew it was simple, but have been staring at this too long ;)